# Project management blogs

Tags: untagged

Blogs related to project management.

Comment: Hi spc, this isn't really the type of question we're hoping to get here on PMSE, but we don't yet have a blog roll. I searched and couldn't find one on our site. So I made this a community wiki post so that we can build up a collection of blogs for PM. Disclaimer:  I make no guarantees that this question will remain open. It's up to our community to decide it's fate. This also shouldn't be used as evidence that similar questions should be asked here. :)

Comment: Discussion on this post is here: http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/409/do-we-want-this-list-of-blogs-blogroll-on-our-site

Comment: Please define important and what aspect of project management you have not been able to find covered by blogs.

Comment: Most important to you. The ones that you watch/read on a regular basis

Comment: @spc, please see our meta discussion. http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/409/do-we-want-this-list-of-blogs-blogroll-on-our-site. I occasionally go look at [top users' profiles](http://pm.stackexchange.com/users) when I want to look at their blogs. This is perhaps the best way to find interesting content to read (that isn't on PMSE, of course ;) ). Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

### General Project Management

---

**Pawel Brodzinski on Software Project Management**

A blog about software project management

http://blog.brodzinski.com/

---

**Mark Phillips Project Management Blog**

A blog about project management.

http://www.vertabase.com/blog/

---

Answer (score 1):

### Agile Focused Project Management

**Erik Willeke's Blog - Rediscovering the Obvious**

A Blog about agile processes.

http://ericwilleke.com/

---

**Agile Buddy Blog**

A blog about simplifying agile project management

http://blog.agilebuddy.com/

---

Comment: You're welcome. But please be sure to note these down. I'm not sure we're going to keep this question here because it goes against the goals of what Stack Exchange is about. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm viewing the sites at the moment. I know that I can always google for something like that, but I wanted to see opinion from people on this site, who are interested in PM.

Comment: Sure, but this isn't really what this site is about. Polling questions are not good Stack Exchange questions. I mentioned you should save these because I cannot guarantee how long this will be here.

Comment: I see. I'm also willing that this network of sites remain hq as they are now and to improve their quality also